# how to disable the comments for specific category in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, comments, categories

How can i disable the comments form for a specific category in Wordpress.
And i mean with that every post the user will publish it in this category will not has a comment form content.

Comment: What have you tried already? Also, can you not disable comments on a per post level from within the Wordpress editor?

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't find the function that i can use to disable the comments on a specific category...

Comment: can you not disable comments on a per post level from within the Wordpress editor?
--> No, cause I wanna do that in the development layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than doing this in functions.php, you could create two template files. The first template file is your standard theme template, the second would be identical, except it wouldn't contain the comment code section.

Simply name the template file that doesn't have the comment code block category_{id}.php and upload to your theme folder. The ID is the ID of the category you want to disable comments on.

More information on category specific templates here https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#category

More information about the comment template here https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comments_template

If you still want to do this via functions.php, see this blog post http://spicemailer.com/wordpress/disable-hide-comments-posts-specific-categories/ which uses the following code snippet

```
add_action( 'the_post', 'st_check_for_closed' );

function st_check_for_closed()
{

global $post;

$my_post_cat = wp_get_post_categories($post->ID);


$disabled_cat = array( "1", "3"); // this is he array of disabled categories. Feel free to edit this line as per your needs. 


$my_result = array_intersect($my_post_cat,$disabled_cat);

    if (empty ( $my_result ) ) 
                  {
        return; 
                   }

     else { 
           add_filter( 'comments_open', 'st_close_comments_on_category', 10, 2 );
           add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'st_deregister_reply_js');

         }
}

      function st_deregister_reply_js() 
    {
    wp_deregister_script( 'comment-reply' );

    }


  function st_close_comments_on_category ($open, $post_id) 
    {
        $open = false;
    }
```